# Why can't I make an AJAX request in Angular to Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax, google-maps

I'm trying to validate a zipcode field in my form in Angular and it's proving to be impossible with the standard DirectionsService.route() so I'm trying to make an $http request.
If I don't specify a method, I get a CORS error. If I set the method to JSONP, it goes through fine, but it doesn't hit my then() function. I just get a parse error. I've tried adding a callback, like documentation suggests, to my URL and that did nothing to fix it.

Why does the Directions API offer so many example URLs throughout their documentation, like "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key=YOUR_API_KEY" if I can't use this method?

```
var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=53703&destination=54481&key=AIzaSyBXbK2tp2WmjBsnwS8QNiqH7QMKxMIZ86A&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
            $http({method:'get', url: url}).then(function(response){
                var data = JSON.parse(angular.fromJson(response.data));
                console.log(data);
            });
```

There is no way I can change this to make a proper request. But it must be possible if they keep showing [examples with URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) and not just directionsService, which does not work for custom validation in Angular.

```
directionsService.route({
        origin: '53075',
        destination: '"'+zip+'"',
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, this.getDistanceCallback);
```

Comment: What does `angular.fromJson` do? `JSON.parse` expects a string; is that what you are supplying from the output of `fromJson`? It look at first glance like you are trying to deserialize the string and then redundantly deserialize the resulting object from the first deserialization (but it's not a string anymore; it's already been deserialized!). What happens if you only use `JSON.parse` *or* `angular.fromJson` (not both)?

Comment: @apsillers angular.fromJson deserializes a JSON string. I've tried so many different things the past few days so things are getting hazy but I wasn't getting back an object or a string persay. It was odd. But after I did JSON.parse, I could parse through it like a JS object. That line though isn't totally relevant to the parse error. It just got carried over from my old callback function. I was receiving a parse error even when everything in my .then() was commented out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by switching to the Mapquest API. Not totally sure what the issue is with Google Maps endpoint. But Mapquest let me do an AJAX request in Angular with ease.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're doing with the directions you are getting back, but I was able to set up a simple app that will list out all the nodes of the `overview_path` of a `route`.

One pain point is that you are going to be loading the Maps API synchronously rather than with a `<script async defer src="...">`.  I think it's kind of weird to have to make a service factory which will I guess resolve whenever you can start using the service.  You can do it, it's just kind of weird.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var mapApp = angular.module("map-app", []);

  mapApp.service("MapSrvc", function($q) {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

    this.getDirections = function(start, end, mode) {
      mode = mode || "DRIVING";
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      directionsService.route({
        origin: start.toString(),
        destination: end.toString(),
        travelMode: mode
      }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === "OK") {
          deferred.resolve(response);
        } else {
          deferred.reject("Something went wrong");
        }
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    };
  });

  mapApp.controller("MapCtrl", function($scope, MapSrvc) {
    $scope.start = 53075;
    $scope.end = 54481;
    $scope.mode = "DRIVING";
    $scope.modes = [{
      name: "Driving",
      mode: "DRIVING"
    }, {
      name: "Walking",
      mode: "WALKING"
    }, {
      name: "Transit",
      mode: "TRANSIT"
    }];
    $scope.directions = [];
    $scope.submitHandler = function() {
      MapSrvc.getDirections($scope.start, $scope.end, $scope.mode).then(function(directions) {
        $scope.directions = directions.routes[0].overview_path.map(function(latlng) {
          return {
            lat: latlng.lat(),
            lng: latlng.lng()
          }
        });
      });
      return false;
    }
  });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBXbK2tp2WmjBsnwS8QNiqH7QMKxMIZ86A"></script>


<main ng-app="map-app">
  <h1>Mapper</h1>
  <div ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <section>
      <h2>Where do you want to go?</h2>
      <form name="mapper" ng-submit="submitHandler()">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Travel Parameters</legend>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <label for="start">Start</label>
              <input id="start" type="text" ng-model="start">
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="end">End</label>
              <input id="end" type="text" ng-model="end">
            </li>
            <li>
              <select ng-model="mode" ng-options="mode.mode as mode.name for mode in modes"></select>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="submit">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Directions</h2>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="direction in directions track by $index">{{direction.lat}}, {{direction.lng}}</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: This is my final code with Mapquest API. http://grab.by/Sulw Just validating that it's an existing proper zipcode. My issue was that I needed it in a directive (not a controller) to validate with $asyncValidators. I could not figure out how to hit the standard async callback for Google Maps. Thank you for the note on the async defer. I would have never thought to remove that. I've heard it's better to have async requests though. I will keep this in mind for next time though in case I decide to use Google Maps again.

Comment: @pinksharpii Ah, ok. Yes, it is better to have the async/defer properties so your page doesn't stall.  I'll see if there is a way to get the `$asyncValidators` to work in case someone else has a similar issue.